# Splashscreen for Phonegapbuild Android not loading

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Does any body here have experience with setting up splash screen for Phonegapbuild Android app?

I am struggling with seeing my splash screen. have tried different approaches I found on the  web but my splash screens still don't load:

In config.xml I have the following

```
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="false" />  
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

The default splash screen is right in the root folder where `index.html` is.

My config.xml looks [like this example](https://gist.github.com/MrTomato8/4f4176a2aed7fe65d523).

Comment: make sure your file name is splash and it is in Android's res/drawable folder. it should work

Comment: Thanks Mo. This is Phonegapbuild issue, not Phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I coded for splash screen android app with phonegap build [v3.3.0].
Added these lines in `config.xml` shared below :-

```
 //Portrait 
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />

//Landscape
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-ldpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" width="320" height="200"  gap:qualifier="land-ldpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-mdpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" width="480" height="320"  gap:qualifier="land-mdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-hdpi-landscape.png"  gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" width="800" height="480"  gap:qualifier="land-hdpi"/>
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/splash/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" width="1280" height="720"  gap:qualifier="land-xhdpi"/>
```

**Note:** Please give the exact name for the images.Take care of width and height. 
Also, `src` must have the absolute source file path for the images. In my case, `res/screen/android/splash/` is  the folder containing splash image files.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this approach but still does not work. My config.xml must have sth wrong or plugin  missing

Answer (score 0):

You don't need these:

```
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="false" />  
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
```

I have working splash screens and I don't use these.

You also don't specify whether this on Android or not. On Android your code should work.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the 2 lines you mentioned and repackaged again. I still see only a white screen. But still the splashscreen does not load. It seems PhonegapBuild searches for the splashscreen in a different folder than the say in the Docs. Where exactly do you have your splash screen?

Comment: I only use one Android Splash screen and it's in the root folder. My iOS splash screens are in there own folder. This can by any folder so I usually have it in images/ios/splash